# Inno Setup need foldername of app constant

Tags: inno-setup

For a specific setup, i need the foldername (without the path) of the {app} constant with a inno-setup script.

So if in the wizard for the 'Select destination folder' the next folder is selected: C:\ProgramFiles\MyAppFolder, i need 'MyAppFolder' in a variable to use in the setup script.

Comment: What if the user chooses `C:\Program Files\SubFolder\MyAppFolder` ? What if the base path won't be `Program Files`, but e.g. `Documents and Settings` ? I mean, how do we recognize the base path ?

Comment: @TLama - I suspect that Dennis wants to slice/cut MyAppFolder from {app} constant (I may be wrong of course). But you are right - Dennis should elaborate.

Comment: if the user chooses c:\program files\subfolder\myappfolder, i need the 'myappfolder'. Do the solution TLama did provide is the right one for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just to get the tail of the [`{app}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#app) path, then you can call [`ExtractFileName`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_extractfilename.htm) function for the path with removed backslash. That returns tail of a given path. In the following script the `PathTail` var will contain the path tail unless the user selects a drive root (like e.g. `C:\`). In that case, the `PathTail` variable will be empty:

```
[Code]
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  PathTail: string;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then
  begin
    PathTail := ExtractFileName(RemoveBackslashUnlessRoot(ExpandConstant('{app}')));
    MsgBox('PathTail: ' + PathTail, mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

Just to be clear, here are examples of what you'll get:

```
User selected                          PathTail contains
----------------------------           ----------------------------
C:\                                    ''
C:\Program Files\AppFolder\            'AppFolder'
C:\Program Files\Subfolder\AppFolder\  'AppFolder'
```